# Initialization for static variables

Tags: c, variables, initialization, static-variables

```
static int i = 5;
static int j = i;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am initializing the static variable by another static variable which is declared before that but also I am getting variable. Please tell me why this is error.

Comment: You can't, `static` variables can only be initialized with constant values.

Comment: C only has a very restrictive concept of "constant", and unfortunately your use case isn't covered by that.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? So maybe a solution could be offered.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the constant value in your code, you can use a macro for the value, then use the macro in both your initializers.

Comment: You can use `static const` instead of just `static`.

Comment: Are you aware that `static` is redundant, in this case? Those variables will have internal linkage and static storage duration regardless of whether you include (or exclude) the `static` keyword.

Comment: @user9000 `const` doesn't imply that the variable is *a constant*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize `j` with `i`, because at compile time, compiler will not know the value of `i`.To assign the value `j = i`, the code need to be executed at run time. When initialize the global or static in C, the compiler and linker need to work together to create the layout of memory. Compiler will give the value and linker need to give the address of the variable. 
The below code will work:

```
static int i = 5;
static int j;

int main()
{
    j=i;    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a real case, you maybe should initialize them explicit.